# NSURLSessionDataTask Fail to upload audio file to server

Tags: ios, objective-c, .net-core

I know this question been asked before. But None of the answers worked for me.

**What is the requirements:**
on iOS app, user to be able to record a short audio file (30sec) then upload it to the server using https request.
The recording and saving temporary on the phone works very well.
But I couldn't get the upload part to work.

My code to upload file on the API side as follow. Tested it with `Postman`, works very well. File received and saved as intended.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile([FromForm] IFormFile file, [FromForm] string name)
    {
        try
        {
            if(webHostEnvironment == null)
            {
                throw new SqlNullValueException("webHostEnvironment is null");
            }

            if (webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath == null)
            {
                throw new SqlNullValueException("webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath is null");
            }


            if(file == null)
            {
                throw new SqlNullValueException("File is null");
            }

            String path = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath,  "uploads");              
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(path, file.FileName);
                using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }
            return BuildResponse(Ok().StatusCode, name);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message );
        }
    }
```

Here's is my Objective-C code to upload the file:

```
-(void)uploadFile:(NSData*)fileData{
if(fileData != nil){
    NSString *fileName = self.temporaryRecFile.path.lastPathComponent;
    NSString *urlString = @"some url";//upload file url
    
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------1234567890";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    
    
    NSMutableData *bodyData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", fileName]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:[NSData dataWithData:fileData]];
    [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    
    [request setHTTPBody:bodyData];
            
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            
            NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
            NSInteger responseStatusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
            
            if(error != nil)
                NSLog(@"error uploading file %@", error.localizedDescription);
            else{
                NSLog(@"response: %lu", responseStatusCode);
                NSLog(@"response: %@", data);
                NSLog(@"response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
            }
        });
    }];
    
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

}
The answer I get is :

```
response: {"code":500,"reason":"File is null"}
```

Instead of `NSURLSessionDataTask` I tried to use `NSURLSessionUploadTask` but with no luck. I got:

```
Failed to read the request form. Multipart body length limit 16384 exceeded
```

Since Postman works very well to upload file using API endpoint. Then the problem must be on the iOS app side.

Any ideas what might be the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: In your posted form data you see, to be sending `name` and `filename` but your server code is complaining that `file` is `null`. It looks like you have inconsistency between your server and client code

Comment: @Paulw11 I also tested `name` on the server and it's null as well.

Comment: What could be the reason of the inconsistency? Could it be that all the API calls/endpoints `content-type` are `application/json` and this is the only `form-data` ? When printing the `response` of the `NSURLSessionDataTask` it says '"Content-Type" = ("application/json");  I don't have much experience in API and core.net so I'm a bit confused

Comment: The content type of the response is set by your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Paulw11 who mentioned the ***inconsistency*** issue. 
Took a fresh look at my code on both sides and realized that I made a mistake on the iOS form by calling the `file` as `userfile`. API expects *file*. So there should be two choices here:
1- Change and rename userfile here: `Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\";` to `file` so that API recognizes it.

2- Or keep any custom name of your choice and modify the API as follow:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile([FromForm(Name = "userfile")] IFormFile file, [FromForm(Name = "filename")] string filename){
      //upload logic here    
    }
```

And that solved my problem and file is now uploaded!